# What / where is the Control Panel executable, really?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, control-panel

There is some weirdness with Control Panel. Right clicking on it in the taskbar brings up a shortcut labeled "Control Panel" (path: `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Control Panel`), which doesn't seem to lead to any real location - "Open File Location" opens a strange folder called "Desktop" that contains many shortcuts not present on my Desktop and is distinct from my actual Desktop folder. Additionally, despite there being a `control.exe` executable in System32, Control Panel doesn't show up as that in Task Manager - rather as explorer. So what is Control Panel really?

Comment: Control Panel is a collection of Apps which you can run independently and you can Control Panel from the  run command https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-open-control-panel/

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* simple answer.

The Control Panel (CPL) has accreted over the years from *many* separate utilities. For example:

- The Classic CPL is shown through `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL`.
- The Immersive CPL is at `"C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe"`.
- The Service CPL *application* is the file services.msc, at `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\services.msc` *and* at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\services.msc`.

Here's a screenshot of some .msc files on this PC:

[image: Search on ext:msc]

[See Auditia](http://www.auditiait.es/en/list-of-commands-msc/) for some more CPL items with extension `msc`.

With each iteration of Windows, the situation gets murkier, with some CPL items implemented in yet other ways. For example, the *Network* CPL can be reached by making a desktop shortcut to `ms-settings:network`, which Windows considers an *internet* shortcut! I guess it just grows [like Topsy](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grow+like+Topsy).

Comment: A lot of legacy apps in Windows *are* internet shortcuts... Sorta...  They are HTAs - [HTML applications] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application#:~:text=An%20HTML%20Application%20(HTA)%20is,used%20for%20the%20program%20logic.}.  Basically a local website that looks like an application.  In a weird way, they were the precursor to modern day Electron apps.

Comment: @Keltari, thanks for the clarification! As in *My Fair Lady*, "One common CPL I'm afraid we'll never get." Though fragmented, each part does work (sometimes redundantly), but i makes it harder to find.

Comment: I think, the question is, where the distinct appearance of the CP folder interface is stored. I think, it is in some dll.

Comment: @Anixx, in **many** DLL's and in **many** executables -- not singular "dll".

Comment: I meant the view of the CP folder not CP modules.